# Won't run .exe correctly on Windows Server

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I'm trying to run a Console Application on Windows Server 2019 (x64).
After i run .exe on the server then writes the following error:

> Could not load or assembly 'MySql.Data'

..etc for all dependencies.

I tried to run just the .exe file (i didn't copy the whole Release directory) on a few PC and it is working well. All of them Win 64bit.
On the server, .exe only work if i copy the whole /Release directory.

I also build and release app with 'Any Cpu' option.

Any tip why i need to copy the whole /bin/release directory to run .exe?
Why not enough just the .exe file?

Many thanks!

Comment: This is probably because the dependency is missing for MySql.  The dependency you need to install on the server is Connector/NET which can be downloaded easily from the MySql homepage

Comment: You should always ship those kinds of dependencies with your app. If it works on one PC that's probably because the related software is installed on that PC. You shouldn't rely on that.

Comment: It most likely works on the PCs because the `MySql.Data` dll exists in the gac. Either install the relevant package on the server, or copy the entire release folder. Although an installer would be better,

Comment: Can i include dependencies into exe file?

Comment: No. You need to create an installer. ClickOnce or via the WixToolset. Or with the coming .Net Core 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exe file doesn't contain the used dlls, just references to the dlls. That's why they are in the release directory and the reason you need to copy the whole directory.

Kind regards
Bernd